# Counting keys that has value that occurs more than one in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I need help with counting in dictionary. I wondered how I can count number of how many times a key has a different value. Example d = {'hello':a, 'hello':b, 'hello':c}. This is going to be counted as 1, since the key "Hello" has a value that has occured more than once. As you may have understood, my goal is to count all the keys that has valuce occurence more than once. So if the key "vop" has value occurrence more than 5 and the key "lop" has value occurrence more than 2, this is going to be countes as 2 since both has occured more than once.

Comment: With a python dictionary, a key must be unique, and can only holds one value. I think you have your keys and values reversed.

Comment: I totaly forgot that a dictionary could only have one key of the same. Thanks for the answer!